# Intellij idea 13.1 and TomEE - hot swapping not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, gradle, apache-tomee, hotswap

I'm working on a Java project that is deployed on TomEE Server (version: apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.6.0.2) & JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5 Ultimate edition. And I build everything with Gradle.

When I'm in debug mode (remote debugger / application server debugger) and trying to do `HotSwap` (after changing one of the classes a bit and clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) the IDE claims:

```
3:25:54 PM All files are up-to-date 
3:25:54 PM Loaded classes are up to date. Nothing to reload.
```

but I know the files changed...

Adding watch while debugging shows me that the class is still in it's prev. state - no changes updated.

But when I do the same process on co-worker station everything works great, in both modes. (remote/application server) the changes update the server after `Make`.

The configuration is identical on both stations. (via SVN and manual triple checking)

What can be wrong? Where else to check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old, but I just had the same problem (with IntelliJ Idea 2018.1 and Wildfly 10) and wanted to share my research results:

For me the problem was a drifting system clock. My development machine has the home-directories (where my Idea projects live on) mounted via NFS (network file system). Unfortunately after some system-update, the NTP (network time protocol) client was no longer running and system times from development machine and NSF-server drifted away, which lead to the problem. Syncing the clocks solved the problem immediately.

Another useful link from JetBrains support forum, that might help is https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000110004-HotSwap-Loaded-classes-are-up-to-date-Nothing-to-reload-on-PC-not-on-laptop